# Eloquent $model->update() does not make changes on database record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I update my comment it goes back to the page and changes the comment back to orignal, so the update hasn't been done. No errors or something.

db: comments

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('articleID')->unsigned();
        $table->string('comment');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['comment', 'articleID'];

    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
}
```

CommentsController

```
public function edit($commentID) {
    $comment = Comment::findOrFail($commentID);
    return view('pages.comments.edit', compact('comment'));
}

public function update($commentID, CommentRequest $request) {
    $comment = Comment::findOrFail($commentID);
    $comment->update($request->all());
    return view('/');
}
```

editComment view

```
    <form action="{{ route('updateComments', ['commentID' => $comment->id]) }}"     class="form-horizontal" method="get">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        <!-- Article data -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="body">Comment</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="body" name="body" maxlength="1000">{{ $comment->comment }}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Article Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping in a try and catch to see if you get any issues, or at least checking the result of `$comment->update($request->all());` so `$test = $comment->update($request->all()); dd($test);  Also check you have nothign caching, so check the db and that its updated there??

Comment: Where is that `$comment->update()` defined? Okay I think I found it. But not in the docs.

Comment: it doesn't update in database either

Comment: 1. change method in form from `get` to `post` to make it able to post it as usual. 2. change field name from `body` to `comment`. 3. `return view('/')` is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

1. You cannot do form submit with `get` method, even with hidden `method_field('PATCH')` in fact it does not event get to update action (:
2. Your form field name `body` is not correct if we look at `fillable` field of model

So just fix Your form:

```
<form 
      action="{{ route('updateComments', ['commentID' => $comment->id]) }}"
      method="post"
      class="form-horizontal">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <!-- Article data -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <textarea 
              id="comment" 
              name="comment" 
              maxlength="1000"
              class="form-control"
            >{{ $comment->comment }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Article Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit comment
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

or change Your schema and model to have field called `body` not `comment`

p.s. also fix Your update action:

```
public function update(CommentRequest $request, $commentID) {
    $comment = Comment::findOrFail($commentID);
    $comment->update($request->except(['articleID'])); // for safety we are ignoring "possible existence" of articleID in forma
    return redirect(route('updateComments', compact('commentID')));
}
```

doing `return view('/')` is not correct - it's trying to find file with name `/` that of course does not exist.

Comment: Now I get a methodNotAllowedException but in my Route I have it post:..
Route::get('comments/edit/{commentID}', 'CommentsController@edit')->name('editComments');
Route::post('comments/update/{commentID}', 'CommentsController@update')->name('updateComments');

Comment: oh! have You seen that I've set in my answer that method must be `post` not `method="get"` ?  just copy-paste it from my answer (:

Comment: Yes I submit my form with post

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers sorry my fault, fixed my answer, I did not realized that You've custom `Route::post`, so just removed `method_field` property, cuz it's not `Route::put` or `Route::patch`. Copy-paste form again (:

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers if You'll have questions about Laravel skype me: `anarjafarov` - I'm glad to help

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers changed update action in my answer for safety, to not to make able to bad guys put comment to another article by setting `articleID` field in form using chrom inspector, or firefox firebug (;